# How to remove special character from email using codeignitor

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to remove special character from email using codeignitor

Email is adding some special character don't know why and how this is going using codeignitor how to solve this this is my Email.php system file please guide

```
protected function _build_message()
    {
        if ($this->wordwrap === TRUE && $this->mailtype !== 'html')
        {
            $this->_body = $this->word_wrap($this->_body);
        }

        $this->_set_boundaries();
        $this->_write_headers();

        $hdr = ($this->_get_protocol() === 'mail') ? $this->newline : '';
        $body = '';

        switch ($this->_get_content_type())
        {
            case 'plain' :

                $hdr .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset='.$this->charset.$this->newline
                    .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: '.$this->_get_encoding();

                if ($this->_get_protocol() === 'mail')
                {
                    $this->_header_str .= $hdr;
                    $this->_finalbody = $this->_body;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->_finalbody = $hdr.$this->newline.$this->newline.$this->_body;
                }

                return;

            case 'html' :

                if ($this->send_multipart === FALSE)
                {
                    $hdr .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset='.$this->charset.$this->newline
                        .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable';
                }
                else
                {
                    $hdr .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="'.$this->_alt_boundary.'"';

                    $body .= $this->_get_mime_message().$this->newline.$this->newline
                        .'--'.$this->_alt_boundary.$this->newline

                        .'Content-Type: text/plain; charset='.$this->charset.$this->newline
                        .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: '.$this->_get_encoding().$this->newline.$this->newline
                        .$this->_get_alt_message().$this->newline.$this->newline.'--'.$this->_alt_boundary.$this->newline

                        .'Content-Type: text/html; charset='.$this->charset.$this->newline
                        .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'.$this->newline.$this->newline;
                }

                $this->_finalbody = $body.$this->_prep_quoted_printable($this->_body).$this->newline.$this->newline;

                if ($this->_get_protocol() === 'mail')
                {
                    $this->_header_str .= $hdr;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->_finalbody = $hdr.$this->newline.$this->newline.$this->_finalbody;
                }

                if ($this->send_multipart !== FALSE)
                {
                    $this->_finalbody .= '--'.$this->_alt_boundary.'--';
                }

                return;

            case 'plain-attach' :

                $hdr .= 'Content-Type: multipart/'.$this->multipart.'; boundary="'.$this->_atc_boundary.'"';

                if ($this->_get_protocol() === 'mail')
                {
                    $this->_header_str .= $hdr;
                }

                $body .= $this->_get_mime_message().$this->newline
                    .$this->newline
                    .'--'.$this->_atc_boundary.$this->newline
                    .'Content-Type: text/plain; charset='.$this->charset.$this->newline
                    .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: '.$this->_get_encoding().$this->newline
                    .$this->newline
                    .$this->_body.$this->newline.$this->newline;

            break;
            case 'html-attach' :

                $hdr .= 'Content-Type: multipart/'.$this->multipart.'; boundary="'.$this->_atc_boundary.'"';

                if ($this->_get_protocol() === 'mail')
                {
                    $this->_header_str .= $hdr;
                }

                $body .= $this->_get_mime_message().$this->newline.$this->newline
                    .'--'.$this->_atc_boundary.$this->newline

                    .'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="'.$this->_alt_boundary.'"'.$this->newline.$this->newline
                    .'--'.$this->_alt_boundary.$this->newline

                    .'Content-Type: text/plain; charset='.$this->charset.$this->newline
                    .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: '.$this->_get_encoding().$this->newline.$this->newline
                    .$this->_get_alt_message().$this->newline.$this->newline.'--'.$this->_alt_boundary.$this->newline

                    .'Content-Type: text/html; charset='.$this->charset.$this->newline
                    .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'.$this->newline.$this->newline

                    .$this->_prep_quoted_printable($this->_body).$this->newline.$this->newline
                    .'--'.$this->_alt_boundary.'--'.$this->newline.$this->newline;

            break;
        }

        $attachment = array();
        for ($i = 0, $c = count($this->_attachments), $z = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
        {
            $filename = $this->_attachments[$i]['name'][0];
            $basename = ($this->_attachments[$i]['name'][1] === NULL)
                ? basename($filename) : $this->_attachments[$i]['name'][1];

            $attachment[$z++] = '--'.$this->_atc_boundary.$this->newline
                .'Content-type: '.$this->_attachments[$i]['type'].'; '
                .'name="'.$basename.'"'.$this->newline
                .'Content-Disposition: '.$this->_attachments[$i]['disposition'].';'.$this->newline
                .'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'.$this->newline
                .(empty($this->_attachments[$i]['cid']) ? '' : 'Content-ID: <'.$this->_attachments[$i]['cid'].'>'.$this->newline);

            $attachment[$z++] = $this->_attachments[$i]['content'];
        }

        $body .= implode($this->newline, $attachment).$this->newline.'--'.$this->_atc_boundary.'--';
        $this->_finalbody = ($this->_get_protocol() === 'mail')
            ? $body
            : $hdr.$this->newline.$this->newline.$body;

        return TRUE;
    }
```

What would be right approach to fix it please guide thanks in advance

one more thing i would like to tell i'm using smtp_crypto => tls that causing issue

Comment: you can use `preg_replace()` for this problem [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: can you please elobrate where to change this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fix this issue by replacing instances of `_prep_quoted_printable` in the Email class with the PHP native function `quoted_printable_encode`.

Just replace inside `_build_message()`

How this help you !